Conditions for Ratio Test
While working on an assignment I came across two series that gave me a bit of trouble.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 15ne^{-n}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{5^{2n+1}} $$


When I applied the ratio test to the first question I defined my $a_{n+1}$ as $15(n+1)\times e^{-n+1}$ and I found my limit as n approaches infinity to be just e. However the answer came back wrong and after redoing this problem I arrive at the right answer when I defined $a_{n+1}$ as $15(n-1) \times e^{-n-1}$ which gave me the limit $\frac{1}{e}$. My textbook states that the ratio I should be comparing the original to should be $a_{n+1}$ not $a_{n-1}$ so I would like some clarification on what may have went wrong during my calculation.
With the second problem, something similar occurred when I defined my $a_{n+1}$ as $\frac{1}{5^{2n+2}} $ which gave me a limit of $\frac{1}{5}$. Checking the answer, the correct limit was $\frac{1}{25}$ which meant that $a_{n+1}$ was $\frac{1}{5^{2n+3}}$. But this sequence looks like the ratio would have to be $a_{n+2}$ which does not match with my textbooks definition of the Ratio test.
Thank you in advance.

The TeX \times can be useful when you want to show a multiplication.

Thanks, I appreciate the help in formatting since I'm new to this and all.

-$-(n+1)$ is different from $-n+1$. Thus, even if you had kept $a_{n+1}$, you should have used $15(n+1)e^{-(n+1)}$ and not $15(n+1)e^{-n+1}$.

I think that you'd find all this clearer if you wrote down explicitly what $a_k$ is. Then you don't "define" $a_{n+1}$, you know what it is, you can write down $a_{n+1}/a_n$ and then work out the limit.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by writing down $a_k$ explicitly? Also why would it be a good idea to not define $a_{n+1}$?

Yathi, you commented that I should have used -(n+1) instead of -n+1 so does this mean that N is like a placeholder where you plug in n+1 for N when you Ratio test? This would make sense for the second problem because 2(n+1)+1 = 2n+3.

@Jake Smith Yes, you are right.

In the first problem, if we define $a_n = 15ne^{-n}$, then $a_{n+1} = 15(n+1)e^{-(n+1)} = 15(n+1)e^{-n-1}$. You made the error of "assuming" that $-(n+1) =-n+1$.
In the other case you made the same error. First define $a_n = \frac{1}{5^{2n+1}}$. Then, $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{5^{2(n+1)+1}} =\frac{1}{5^{2n+3}}$. Here the error you made is saying that $2(n+1)+1 = 2n+2$. Be careful when pluying in your $n$ value into $a_n$
